# Could LUIS share entity definition among multiple models?

Tags: azure, nlp, azure-language-understanding, azure-machine-learning-service

We have serval [LUIS](http://luis.ai) models that work fine and returns desired [Intents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent) and [Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-entity-types).

Models are separated based on content and target business domain so we do not want to merge them.
Still there are some [Regex entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-intents-regex-entity) that are the same in each of the model.

---

If we'd like to have one Regex definition at one place could we eventually share such definition among multiple LUIS models?

Right now we proceed with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could share the entire app by [cloning the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-versions). And the only way to use specific entities would be to delete the others.

> If we'd like to have one Regex definition at one place could we eventually share such definition among multiple LUIS models?
>
> Right now we proceed with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V

This is the only way to do it right now.